# Is it possible to run a single instance apache ignite configuration? Or must there be multiple instances clustered together?

Tags: ignite

I'm using Ignite as a Hibernate L2 Cache Provider on a single-node/single-instance install, so I don't want any clustering or network communication going on. Is there a property I can set in IgniteConfiguration in the XML to disable networking/clustering?

Is it possible to run Apache Ignite as a single instance only?

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <!--
        Specify the name of the caching grid (should correspond to the
        one in Hibernate configuration).
    -->
    <property name="gridName" value="hibernate-grid"/>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="dataRegionName" value="object"/>
                <property name="name" value="object"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="LOCAL"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                <!-- Enabling on-heap caching for this cache. -->
                <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                    <!-- LRU eviction policy. -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                        <property name="maxSize" value="5000"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="object"/>
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I keep getting this:

```
SEVERE: Failed to request nodes addresses.
java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF: address not bound to any interface
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSetOption(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:309)
        at java.net.MulticastSocket.setInterface(MulticastSocket.java:466)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.requestAddresses(TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.java:565)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.access$700(TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.java:80)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder$AddressReceiver.body(TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.java:780)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` with sole `127.0.0.1` address?

```
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: The following link provides additional details about isolating Ignite cluster https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#isolated-ignite-clusters-on-same-set-of-machines

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it appears that this doesn't quite work. It does eliminate some of the errors, but the node still does not startup (it just hangs, printing this: 

WARNING: Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2 secs): [/127.0.0.1:47500] 

because it finds no peers, apparently (as best as I can read the docs, it will wait forever to join a cluster, but I have no cluster, only the single instance)

Comment: @clemep No, it should not wait for peers, one node should be self-sufficient. By any chance does that change if you add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` JVM arg? It's not a client node, right?

Comment: @clemep Sounds like you're starting a client node which indeed will not start unless there is at list one server node within provided addresses is running. Another possibility is that port 47500 is occupied by something else, so node tries to bind to 47501, 47502, etc. Try to provide a range of several ports in IP finder like this: `127.0.0.1:47500..47509`

Comment: thanks, yes, was in client mode...now I'm trying to work out how to get spring bean injection to work...does instantiation of org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean bean call Ignition.start() ?

Comment: @clemep it should be in server mode, and I believe Spring should start it automatically after context is set up.